# Function works onClick but not when called in a different method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to trigger this without a button click. It works fine onClick but not at all when called in a different function. My code looks like this:

```
isCorrect = (newOrder) => {

for (let i = 0 ; i < newOrder.length; i ++) {
  if( this.state.displayPlayers[newOrder[i]].rank !== i) {
    console.log('loser')
    return
  }
}
console.log('winner')
this.random();
}


random = () => {
this.setState({
  order: [4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
 });
};
```

this.setState works on the button click but not when called in the larger function. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my handleMouseMove function which triggers the isCorrect function.

```
handleMouseMove = ({ pageY }) => {
    const {
      isPressed,
      topDeltaY,
      order,
      originalPosOfLastPressed
    } = this.state;

    if (isPressed) {
      const mouseY = pageY - topDeltaY;
      const currentRow = clamp(Math.round(mouseY / 100), 0, itemsCount - 1);
      let newOrder = order;

      if (currentRow !== order.indexOf(originalPosOfLastPressed)) {
        newOrder = reinsert(
          order,
          order.indexOf(originalPosOfLastPressed),
          currentRow
        );
        this.isCorrect(newOrder)
      }
      //console.log(newOrder);
      //console.log(this.state);
      this.setState({ mouseY: mouseY, order: newOrder });

    }
```

this is my entire render/ return statement:

```
render() {
    const { mouseY, isPressed, originalPosOfLastPressed, order } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="demo8">
        <Button onClick = {() => this.random()}> click </Button>
        <Button onClick={this.ypcGame}> ypc game</Button>

        {this.state.displayPlayers.map((player, i) => {
          //console.log(i);
          const style =
            originalPosOfLastPressed === i && isPressed
              ? {
                  scale: spring(1.1, springConfig),
                  shadow: spring(16, springConfig),
                  y: mouseY
                }
              : {
                  scale: spring(1, springConfig),
                  shadow: spring(1, springConfig),
                  y: spring(order.indexOf(i) * 100, springConfig)
                };
          return (
            <Motion style={style} key={i}>
              {({ scale, shadow, y }) => (
                <div
                  onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown.bind(null, i, y)}
                  onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart.bind(null, i, y)}
                  className={
                    order.indexOf(i) == player.rank
                      ? 'correct demo8-item '
                      : 'incorrect demo8-item'
                  }
                  style={{
                    boxShadow: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px ${shadow}px ${2 *
                      shadow}px 0px`,
                    transform: `translate3d(0, ${y}px, 0) scale(${scale})`,
                    WebkitTransform: `translate3d(0, ${y}px, 0) scale(${scale})`,
                    zIndex: i === originalPosOfLastPressed ? 99 : i
                  }}>
                  {order.indexOf(i)}
                  {order.indexOf(i) == player.rank ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'} :
                  {order.indexOf(i) == player.rank ? null : (complete = false)}
                  {player.displayName}
                </div>
              )}
            </Motion>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: @Caramiriel I'm using react motion and calling it on a conditional on a mouse move. I've edited to add the function.

Comment: Is all this code in the same component?

Comment: currently yes @jmargolisvt

Comment: @LuizAlmeida Can you add the code for correctly working `onClick` w/ `isCorrect` ? It looks like it relies on `reinsert` which indirectly is effected by `pageY` from MouseMove's event.

Comment: @SILENT added the return statement

Comment: can you post where in the code are you attaching the handleMouseMove handler?

Comment: @LuizAlmeida Where is onClick's `isCorrect` called? I don't see it. Does it also use `pageY`? There is insufficient info to properly assess your problem but I bet as long as you provide a properly formatted `newOrder` array to `isCorrect`, it should work.